# how to get indication if a call to Wireshark dissector from another dissector was successfully

Tags: tcp, lua, wireshark, lua-table, wireshark-dissector

I have 2 tcp dissectors which listens to same port.
Therefore i chose to have a base dissector which listens to that port and this base dissector holds the information for the 2 tcp dissectors.
when a packet arrives for that port, the base dissector makes a foreach loop and try's to call every one of the 2 tcp dissectors by its turn.

I'm using the code line:

```
res = Dissector.get("first_tcp_dissector"):call(buffer, pinfo, tree)
```

I'm expecting that if the called dissector successfully parsed the packet it will return a number (if that packet is not for it, it return 0).

but `dissector:call(tvb, pinfo, tree)` doesn't return anything and i dont have any indication if the parsing succeded.

How can i get the true return value of the first_tcp_dissector or fairly some indication if the parsing succeeded?
(By the way, i dont want to use heuristic...)

Answer (score 2):

*but `dissector:call(tvb, pinfo, tree)` doesn't return anything*

Are you sure?  Because if you look at the source code, [`Dissector_call()`](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/wslua/wslua_dissector.c;h=b365c7e6d6b70ed90152d6686f8c426f96f1c567;hb=HEAD#l94) returns the *"`Number of bytes dissected.`"*

Perhaps you're running an older version of Wireshark prior to [this](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=commitdiff;h=8c0d3ae47e35f6692b91ab776919391f52700829) change made by Stig Bjørlykke committed by Anders Broman on 17 June 2014?